# Animating/Moving a shape to specific coordinates?

Tags: c#, animation

I'm randomly generating two rectangles, the first rectangle stays where it is but I want to move/animate the second rectangle so that it's bottom right corner is equalto the position occupied by the top left corner of the first, atm what I've basically got is;

```
if(count != 300)
{
    rect2.X = count + (rect1.X - 100);
    rect2.Y = count + (rect1.Y - 100);
    count +=2
}
```

This is inside a timer event, but is obviously not quite what I want, I've tried multiple variations of the above but none seem to do the job.

I'm sure there'll be an annoyingly simple answer to this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What seems to be the problem with this code? Where are you painting to (i.e. a picture box)? I think you should take into account the distance between the rectangles (if they are random) to adjust the size of the step or the length of the animation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Neither where it's being painted to nor the step size (which dictates speed) have any bearing on the start or finish position of the rectangle, which is what I'm interested in right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming top left of the screen is `{0,0}` and bottom right is `{screenWidth, screenHeight}`
I'm also assuming floating point coordinates here (i.e. Rect.X is a `double` or `float`). If they aren't, you'll need to do some work in step 2 below to make sure you move an even amount of pixels in each step.

Here's the basic algorithm, in pseudo code:

1. Calculate final location for your animating rectangles top-left corner: `finalPos = {r1.x + r1.width, r1.y+r1.width}`
2. Decide how many steps you want, and calculate how far the rectangle should move each step.
   Let's take 100 steps for example. `dx = r2.x - finalPos.x / 100`, `dy = r2.y - finalPos.y / 100`
3. In each timer event, you just add `dx` and `dy` to your animating rectangle's position:

Like so:

```
if (currentStep < 300)
{
    r2.x += dx;
    r2.y += dy;
    currentStep++;
}
else
{
    // We're done
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Of course, if you are using a graphical framework to draw stuff, you may already have access to an animation framework that can do the above for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use WPF it is pretty straightforward:

In the window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                      Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRect"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                      To="{Binding ElementName=FixedRect, Path=(Canvas.Left)}" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                      Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRect"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                      To="{Binding ElementName=FixedRect, Path=(Canvas.Top)}" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Name="FixedRect"
                   StrokeThickness="2"
                   Stroke="Black"
                   Width="{Binding R1.Width}"
                   Height="{Binding R1.Height}"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding R1.X}"
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding R1.Y}"/>
        <Rectangle Name="AnimatedRect"
                   StrokeThickness="2"
                   Stroke="Black"
                   Width="{Binding R2.Width}"
                   Height="{Binding R2.Height}"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding R2.X}"
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding R2.Y}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        Rect r1 = new Rect();
        r1.X = rnd.Next(500);
        r1.Y = rnd.Next(500);
        r1.Width = rnd.Next(50,100);
        r1.Height = rnd.Next(50, 100);
        R1 = r1;

        Rect r2 = new Rect();
        r2.X = rnd.Next(500);
        r2.Y = rnd.Next(500);
        r2.Width = rnd.Next(50, 100);
        r2.Height = rnd.Next(50, 100);
        R2 = r2;


        DataContext = this;
    }

    public Rect R1 { get; set; }
    public Rect R2 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I tried it out of curiosity and it throws an AnimationException - Cannot animate the 'Top' property on a 'System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the inner exception.

Comment: Yeah, for WPF you can only animate dependency properties. If you are in WPF, you should animate the TranslateTransform of the things you are rendering (i.e. the actual visual elements)